# Tkinter Treeview widget, Scrollbar issue

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

**I am trying to add a scroll bar which is in sync with the player's name, position, height, weight and colleges but I can only scroll through the players table (*treeview*).**

**Could someone please help me and provide me code to the scrollbar issue?**

here is the code :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("850x500")

none = []

player = open('NBA n ABA players.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
content = player.readlines()
players = [s.strip('\n') for s in content]


pos = open('pos.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
content2 = pos.readlines()
positions = [s.strip('\n') for s in content2]

ht = open('ht.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
content3 = ht.readlines()
hts = [s.strip('\n') for s in content3]

wt = open('wt.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
content4 = wt.readlines()
wts = [s.strip('\n') for s in content4]

college = open('colleges.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
content5 = college.readlines()
colleges = [s.strip('\n') for s in content5]

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=1, height=len(players), show="headings")
tree_pos = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=1, height=len(positions), show="headings")
tree_ht = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=1, height=len(hts), show="headings")
tree_wt = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=1, height=len(wts), show="headings")
tree_col = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=1, height=len(colleges), show="headings")

tree.pack(side='left')
tree_pos.pack(side='left')
tree_ht.pack(side='left')
tree_wt.pack(side='left')
tree_col.pack(side='left')

tree.heading(1, text="NBA / ABA PLAYERS")
tree_pos.heading(1, text="Position")
tree_ht.heading(1, text="Height")
tree_wt.heading(1, text="Weight")
tree_col.heading(1, text="Colleges")


tree.column(1, width=140)
tree_pos.column(1, width=140)
tree_ht.column(1, width=140)
tree_wt.column(1, width=140)
tree_col.column(1, width=240)

scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')

for x in players:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=[x])

for x in positions:
        tree_pos.insert('', 'end', values=[x])

for x in hts:
        tree_ht.insert('', 'end', values=[x])

for x in wts:
        tree_wt.insert('', 'end', values=[x])

for x in colleges:
        tree_col.insert('', 'end', values=[x])


root.mainloop()
```

link for screenshot of output window here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXYMv.png

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use QtDesigner for QTPython. Its very easy to use. It just like Tkinter GUI but difference it will allow drag and drop GUI.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Although great advice on the path to troubleshooting, the question is to identify which part of the code is causing issues.